# Performing jsx transforms on the client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm building an application which allows users to build and apply their own components and templates. I want to allow users to edit strings of jsx data and then perform the transform client-side for render.

While the in the [in browser transform](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#jsx) performs jsx transforms on embedded scripts, and [react-tools](https://www.npmjs.org/package/react-tools) is available on the server, I can't determine how to make the transform function available to the client.

The inline browser transform doesn't appear to have provide any methods for access, and Atomify/Browserify crashes when I try to using the react-tools transform on the client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `JSXTransformer` module exports two functions:

- `transform` takes JSX source code as a string and returns an object with a key named `code` whose value is a JavaScript string that can then be eval'd.
- `exec` works like `transform` and the result is then passed to `eval`.

This call:

```
JSXTransformer.transform("React.createClass({render: function() { return <div></div>; } });").code
```

...produces this plain JavaScript output:

```
"React.createClass({render: function() { return React.createElement("div", null); } });"
```

Comment: Great! 

But my problem is: how do I make the JSXTransformer module available on the client?

Comment: Ahh, for some reason I was missing it when I made it a global. All clear now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JSXTransformer was [deprecated in mid-2015](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html) in favor of Babel's in-browser solution, `babel-standalone`: https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation

Discussion here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5497